# Combining Cumulative Flow Diagram with trendlines

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard

I am looking for a way to plot a cumulative flow diagram that includes trend-lines on Azure Devops Dashboard. Are there any default / extension widgets that will allow this?

[image: 1]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, the trend-line feature you're looking for is not available. The [Analytics Widgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/what-is-analytics?view=azure-devops) provided with Azure DevOps can handle the majority of use cases but the Cumulative Flow Diagram doesn't understand the concept of end-date which is what is required to create an ideal trend.

There are other options:

- Excel. There is an [Office integration for Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/track-work?view=azure-devops&tabs=open-excel) and if you can get the raw data you want from a basic Query, you can play with the data in Excel
- Power BI. By far a better option than Excel because it leverages the analytics views and [you can build some pretty amazing views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-quick-report?view=azure-devops).

**Update:**

Few additional links:

- Creating a [Cumulative Flow diagram](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-cfd?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi) in Power BI using Azure DevOps Analytics views
- [Limitations of adding a trendline to stacked-chart visuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-analytics-pane) is described as:

> The following visuals can use only a constant line from the Analytics pane:
>
> - Stacked area chart
> - Stacked bar chart
> - Stacked column chart
> - Waterfall chart
> - 100% Stacked bar chart
> - 100% Stacked column chart
>
> The following visuals can use a trend line if there's time data:
>
> - Area chart
> - Clustered column chart
> - Line chart
> - Line and clustered column chart
> - Scatter chart

- One power-user has suggested that you [could create a line chart with the same synchronized axis and overlay it on top](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Trendline-on-quot-Stacked-column-chart-quot/m-p/1058672/highlight/true#M494716). I don't fully understand how you can have a trend-line for stacked data, so this approach would only work if the trendline is for the bottom unstacked column.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have tried both Excel and Power BI, but couldn't find any visuals that allows a trend-line to be plotted on a stacked area chart. Do you have suggestions of visuals that would allow this? Thank you!